# 1st Yr Probability Question: trying to figure out the joint pmf of 2 Binomial RVs, am I on the right track?

Tags: probability

**Question**

- There are $n+m$ independent trials, success probability $p$
- $X = $ # of successes in first $n$ trials
- $Z = $ total # of successes in $n+m$ trials

What is the joint pmf of $X$ and $Z$?

**My attempt**

I think the answer is...

$$P(X=x,Z=z) = \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \binom{m}{z-x} p^{z-x} (1-p)^{m-z+x}$$

Assuming $x\le n$ and $z-x\le m$

I thought about various test cases like $P(X=0,Z=4)$ etc, and it seems to be correct...

Thanks for your help and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
P(X=x, Z=z)&=P(X=x, Y=z-x)\\
&=P(X=x)P(Y=z-x) \text{, by independence} \\
&= \begin{cases} \binom{n}{x} p^x (1-p)^{n-x} \binom{m}{z-x} p^{z-x} (1-p)^{m-z+x}&, 0 \le x \le n, 0\le z-x \le m \\
0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
 \\
&= \begin{cases} \binom{n}{x}\binom{m}{z-x} p^z (1-p)^{m+n-z} &, 0 \le x \le n, 0\le z-x \le m \\
0& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: Very interesting... I think $X$ and $Z$ are dependent. How do you know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent... for example if $X=z$ then you know that $Y=0$. What is the flaw in my last statement? I think I actually did the same thing of creating that RV $Y$ without realizing it... Thanks!!!

Comment: Yes, $X$ and $Z$ are dependent, that is why we can't write $P(X=x, Z=z)=P(X=x)P(Z=z)$. However, suppose you know that there are $z$ successes in the first trial but I do not tell you how many success are there in total, $Y$ the number of success in the last $m$ trials is not known.

Comment: That is a trip... I think I understand. I will mediate on this.Thanks!